# Calling Two Procedures in [code] from [Run] Afterinstall

Tags: inno-setup

I have two Procedures in my code section Pro1 and Pro2, the pro1 takes value from user and pro2 uses that value so i want these procedures to be executed one after another in same order.
I know that we can call procedure from [Run] section using Afetrinstall. Can i call these two procedures Pro1 and Pro2 using single Afterinstall in the same order?

One more thing, how can i call a particular Filename in the run section based on condition written in the code? is that even possible? can i call the same File name more than once .I'm new to inno can anyone help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Is it possible to assign more than one function to the "AfterInstall" parameter ?***

No, this is not possible, but you can simply call one function from the other. So, you will assign a function to the [`AfterInstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall&anchor=AfterInstall) parameter and the other function call from the assigned one. In script it may look like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: AfterInstallProc

[Code]
procedure AfterInstallProc;
begin
  // do something here
  AnotherProcedure;
end;

procedure AnotherProcedure;
begin
  // do something else here
end;
```

***Is it possible to conditionally assign value to the "Filename" parameter of a [Run] section entry ?***

Yes, it is. You can declare so called [`scripted constant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) which is a constant with assigned function in which you can return the value to the parameter. In a script example like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{code:GetRunEntryFileName}";

[Code]   
function GetRunEntryFileName(Value: string): string;
begin
  // the "SomeCondition" is meant to be a certain variable or statement which
  // evaluates upon your needs; to the Result you'll return the same as you'd
  // write in the script including constants, like e.g. '{app}\MyProg.exe'
  if SomeCondition then
    Result := 'calc.exe'
  else
    Result := 'charmap.exe';
end;
```

The similar you can apply for all the parameters of the [`[Run]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) section except to the [`Flags`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=Flags) parameter, which must be known at compilation time.

***Can I execute the same application from [Run] section ?***

Yes, you can. This section *doesn't care* of what you're executing, so there can be even exactly the same entries, or just entries for the same application multiple times. So even this is possible:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe";
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe";
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Parameters: "/x"
```

But this may have practical sense only if you are running e.g. a certain external installer where you need to call it more than once with different command line parameters. I can't think of a reason to execute the same application the very same way more than once.